# Сохранение значения в сеансе

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Создаю интернет магазин на ASP.NET-MVC5, и нужно сохранить выбранное значение города до окончания сеанса, чтоб оно не обнулялось при переходе по категориям товаров. Как это сделать?

Comment: Можно сохранить это значение в куках браузера.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать куки или сессию, по ссылке есть описание как работать с куками

[habrahabr.ru - ASP.NET MVC Урок 6. Авторизация](https://habrahabr.ru/post/176043/)

Хоть там и про авторизацию но работа с куками очень хорошо описана